# Does somebody know how to fix this error: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component....?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got the error: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. Does anyone know how should I setState in click function to avoid this error? Thanks

```
class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMenu: null
   };
}

showMenu = (id) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showMenu: prevState.showMenu===null ? id : null,
    }))
}

componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>this.click(e))
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', (e)=>this.click(e))
}


click = (e) => {
    if(e.target.className!=='flaticon-menu white'){
      this.setState({
        showMenu:null
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to `bind` your methods in the constructor. See here (second half of the page): https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: arrow functions don't really get removed that easy, just bind `this.click = this.click.bind(this)` in the constructor, and then add/remove the eventListener by using this.click only

Comment: He is using an arrow function so manual binding not required

Comment: The issue is in componentWillUnMount. You are calling this.click in componentWillUnMount method which actually doing setState but unfortunately the component not available anymore because it is already unmounted and that’s why you get that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `removeEventListener` doesn't work. Two arrow functions that look the same are actually not the same:

```
 (e => this.click(e)) === (e => this.click(e)) // false
```

Therefore you have to store the listener to remove it afterwards:

```
 componentDidMount(){
   this.listener = e => this.click(e);
   document.addEventListener('click', this.listener);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   document.removeEventListener('click', this.listener);
}
```

Or you just take `this.click` directly:

```
componentDidMount(){
   document.addEventListener('click', this.click);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   document.removeEventListener('click', this.click);
}
```

Comment: @icepickle it is bound, `click` is an arrow method